# language option in reCAPTCHA ASP.NET plugin

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, recaptcha

I'm using ASP.NET plugin for reCAPTCHA in my ASP.NET MVC application. Recaptcha assembly version is 1.0.4.0. Is there a way to set language to be used for RecaptchaControl?

```
    var captchaControl = new Recaptcha.RecaptchaControl
            {
                ID = "recaptcha",
                Theme = "blackglass",
                PublicKey = "public_key",
                PrivateKey = "private_key"
            };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature was not supported in v1.0.4.0. Please download the latest version and try again.

http://code.google.com/p/recaptcha/downloads/detail?name=recaptcha-dotnet-1.0.5.0-binary.zip

Comment: this is the correct answer to the question. i replied with another solution to the question.

Answer (score 1):

with the help of [this article](http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2008/12/02/using-recaptcha-with-asp-net-mvc.aspx) here is how I've done it. the key is editing the generated html at the end; replacing "RecaptchaOptions = {" with "RecaptchaOptions = { lang : 'supported_language_code',"

```
public static string GenerateCaptcha(this HtmlHelper helper)
{
    var captchaControl = new Recaptcha.RecaptchaControl
            {
                ID = "recaptcha",
                Theme = "clean",
                PublicKey = "public_key_here",
                PrivateKey = "private_key_here"
            };
    var htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(new StringWriter());
    captchaControl.RenderControl(htmlWriter);
    var html = htmlWriter.InnerWriter.ToString();
    html = html.Replace("RecaptchaOptions = {", "RecaptchaOptions = { lang : 'tr', ");
    return html;
}
```

EDIT: A cleaner solution is given [here](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=611). (System.Web.Helpers)