# Is there a way to set custom language strings for the ReCaptcha ASP.Net user control?

Tags: asp.net, localization, recaptcha

I'm using the ReCaptcha ASP.Net user control and I was wondering if anyone is aware of a way of setting custom language strings for the control from markup.

I know how to do it if I'm not using the user control, e.g. setting the RecaptchaOptions javascript variable, but the user control writes its own variable and uses that so that solution won't work, or haven't when I tried anyway.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add tags "asp.net", ".net", if your question is related to these technologies. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy to use the supported languages that are built in, [this SO question is asking how to set the language using the user control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432838/language-option-in-recaptcha-asp-net-plugin) (added in 1.0.5) which I think exposes a publish `Lang` property.

According to the [customisations page from the recaptcha site](http://code.google.com/apis/recaptcha/docs/customization.html#i18n), the supported languages are: English, Dutch, French, German, Portuguese, Russian, Spanish, Turkish

Otherwise, you're going to have to use javascript...if you have created the recaptcha control before using javascript, you could create your own user control, or you could perhaps modify the source (for yourself) of the user control that is provided.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't help. The question is to set custom language strings (since I wasn't using one of the supported languages). I appreciate your answer though.